# Invalid access when attempting to redefine variable

Tags: postscript

I'm attempting to update a variable from within `BeginPage`. When I attempt to redefine it I get:

> invalidAccess

Below is the `postscript`. I've omitted most of the configuration file and I've just pasted the `postscript` which is giving me the issue.

What I'm attempting to do here is `rotate` every `even` page by 180 degrees.
I thought that the definition of `PageCounter` would be stored in the `userdict` which would allow me read/write access but I'm guessing that is not the case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<<
    /PageCounter 1 def
    /BeginPage
    {
        PageCounter 2 mod 0 eq {100 100 translate 180 rotate} if
        /PageCounter PageCounter 1 add def
    }
>> setpagedevice
```

Comment: Are you using ghostscript to redistill a pdf? I find this works: "currentpagedevice /PageCount get" except the page count begins at zero for the first page and then is always 1 less than the page number. The dictionary by definition has a key and a value so your /PageCounter should be a violation.

Comment: No, I’m using Global Graphics HHR to rip a given PDF. I provide the HHR API with the PDF and a configuration file. The configuration file is a postscript file. It’s in this configuration file that I’m doing this. That being said, I’ll give your suggestion a try. Do you mind writing it as an answer?

Comment: The Red Book says the operand stack has the page number when the /BeginPage is called. The page number is related to the showpage operator. I wonder if the pdf has a showpage because the /BeginPage doesn't get that number when using ghostscript to redistill a pdf. If this were postscript then the showpage could be redefined except this is a pdf. My experiments have failed so far. If your solution is working then wow.

Answer (score 2):

**Old Solution**

OK after digging in to the Red/Blue Book a bit more it looks like I found the solution (which when tested worked as expected).

```
<<
    userdict begin /PageCounter 1 def
    /BeginPage
    {
        PageCounter 2 mod 0 eq {100 100 translate 180 rotate} if
        userdict begin /PageCounter PageCounter 1 add def
    }
>> setpagedevice
```

**New Solution**

So the above solution kind of worked but was causing the `postscript` parser to crash when handling multiple jobs. Furthermore, I was using an explicit variable for keeping track of what page I was on, but `BeginPage` gets called with the page count already on the stack.

The page count uses `zero based indexing` which means the first page will be `0` the second will be `1` and so on. To account for this I add `1` to the page count.

```
<<
    % Make sure this is defined at the start of setpagedevice
    /BeginPage
    {
        1 add 2 mod 0 eq { 100 100 translate 180 rotate } if
    } bind
>> setpagedevice
```

Comment: Yes, in your original program you are using whatever dictionary happens to be top of the stack to define your key/value pair. If that's systemdict, or any other read-only dictionary, then you will get an invalidaccess when you try to write to it. explicitly using userdict is one possible solution but if I were you I'd choose a more unique name for the key, all sorts of programs use userdict and if you get a name clash your value may change type or increment/decerment unexpectedly if the main program happens to use the same key in userdict.

Comment: The old solution might work better if you stick an `end` at the end after the `def`. Otherwise you're leaving userdict on top of the dictstack which the program probably isn't expecting (otherwise you wouldn't need to put it there to begin with).

Answer (score 2):

This is as close as I can get before things flip and disappear with my testing pdf. I suspect they could vary. I am getting sleepy. I pop the operand off the stack and use /PageCount instead. Remember the count is 1 less in begin page. I am glad you have another solution.

```
%!
<<
/BeginPage { pop currentpagedevice /PageCount get 2 mod 1 eq{ 45 rotate 300 -300 translate}if }
>> setpagedevice
```

EDIT: This works with ghostscript. I finally defeated the auto rotate function except also thought the /Tumble should work. I just have a simplex printer so don't use duplex/tumble settings. So I wonder if this will work for your type of distiller or printer:

```
%!
<<
/BeginPage {
pop currentpagedevice /PageCount get 2 mod 1 eq{
180 rotate -612 -792 translate
}if }
>> setpagedevice

<< /AutoRotatePages /None >> setpagedevice
```

Comment: OK so I was able to figure it out. Your solution on using the `PageCount` is what pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: You can put both definitions in the same dictionary and do just one call to `setpagedevice`.